# I am using Input component with semantic ui react but could not see placeholder and could not set value

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I am using webpack, babel, typescript, newest React version. Could not see placeholder and could not set value when I am using Input component. This is very simple code.

When I look at Chrome debugger, I don't see placeholder there. Something with my environment but I could not figure out what could be the issue.

I actually created couple new environment and it worked there. I also cut everything out from my current enviroment - all libraries that are not used,  all code and all styles. Just left one module with that simple code.

import * as React from "react";
import { Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';

`const LotcheckApp = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Input placeholder='Search...' size='large' />
        </>
    );
};`

export default LotcheckApp;

There is no error messages - just could not see placeholder and could not set value.

Comment: It just one Input on page, that I am trying to se placeholder there.

Comment: I also could not set value for this component.

Comment: I figured out that - it is LodashWebpackPlugin. Is it well known issue with Semantic-ui-react library?